# Trouble with Joomla 2.5 validation rule

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Im' trying to add a validation rule for a form field which must be unique, but it seems the form data is not being passed to the function.

I created the mlsid.php file in administrator/components/com_iproperty/models/rules.

The XML file was modified accordingly.

What is wrong?

```
       defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

    /******************************************
     * Form Rule class for the Joomla Platform.
     *
     * @package     Joomla.Platform
     * @subpackage  Form
     * @since       11.1
     */
    class JFormRuleMlsid extends JFormRule
    {
        /**
         * Method to test the username for uniqueness.
         *
         * @param   SimpleXMLElement  &$element  The SimpleXMLElement object representing the <field /> tag for the form field object.
         * @param   mixed             $value     The form field value to validate.
         * @param   string            $group     The field name group control value. This acts as as an array container for the field.
         *                                       For example if the field has name="foo" and the group value is set to "bar" then the
         *                                       full field name would end up being "bar[foo]".
         * @param   JRegistry         &$input    An optional JRegistry object with the entire data set to validate against the entire form.
         * @param   object            &$form     The form object for which the field is being tested.
         *
         * @return  boolean  True if the value is valid, false otherwise.
         *
         * @since   11.1
         * @throws  JException on invalid rule.
         */
        public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)
        {
            // Get the database object and a new query object.
            $db = JFactory::getDBO();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Build the query.
            $query->select('COUNT(*)');
            $query->from('#__iproperty');
            $query->where('mls_id = ' . $db->quote($value));

            // Get the extra field check attribute.
            $propertyId = ($form instanceof JForm) ? $form->getValue('id') : '';
            $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' <> ' . (int) $propertyId);

                    //This shows that form values are not accesible
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage( 'propertyid is: '. $propertyId );



            //Allow empty Ref
            $query->where('char_length(mls_id) > 0');

            // Set and query the database.
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $duplicate = (bool) $db->loadResult();

            // Check for a database error.
            if ($db->getErrorNum())
            {
                JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
            }

            if ($duplicate)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And where is the validation code?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you modified the xml please? Did you add the path?